# runtimeerror null function or function signature missmatch Unity3d Webgl

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, github, runtime-error, webgl

My problem is that I save 3 variables: record, characters and coins, but when I play in the editor everything works, and when I upload to the github host I get this error. I removed the coins from the scene and everything is functioning, the record and the character's skin is saved, I don't understand what's the matter.I use PlayerPrefs.

I cant find information about this issue

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVh4e.jpg

Comment: Update your question with additional information, do not put the extra information in comments.

Comment: You also have not uploaded any code. I would not recommend GitHub for unity. They have built in support for their own source control, Plastic SCM, which will not have as many issues. Unity may for example mess with the git files, and vice Vera’s.